# Two questions about the empty type

Tags: logic, type-theory

I have two questions regarding the empty type, $0$, in Martin-Löf type theory:

1. I was reading that, in intuitionistic logic, one has $\neg\neg\neg P\rightarrow \neg P$.  This amounts to finding a term of
   $$
   (P\times 0\times 0\rightarrow 0)\rightarrow (P \rightarrow 0)
   $$
2. Is it true that $0\rightarrow P$ for any $P$?  If $P$ is inhabited, then we have $p:P$ and we can just define the constant function.  If $P=0$, then identity works.  But, I can't seem to find a general proof of this fact.

Comment: What you say in 1 is wrong: $\lnot\lnot\lnot P$ is $((P \rightarrow 0) \rightarrow 0) \rightarrow 0$. This is not the same as $P \times 0 \times 0 \rightarrow 0$, which is the uncurrying of $P \rightarrow (0 \rightarrow (0 \rightarrow 0))$, where by convention you can omit the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [intuitionsitic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) we have the rule :

> $\bot \vdash P$, for $P$ whatever

i.e. form the "falsum" (a contradiction) we can derive a proposition whatever.

Thus, by $\rightarrow$-introduction, follows that :

> $\vdash \bot \rightarrow P$.

With $\bot$, the negation is defined as

> $\lnot P := P \rightarrow \bot$.

In Martin-Löf's Type Theory, the empty set ($\{ \}$ or $\Lambda$) takes the role of $\bot$ and we have that $\lnot P := P \rightarrow \{ \}$.

Thus, we must have also $\{ \} \rightarrow P$, for every $P$.